# How to call different functions in loop Python

Tags: python, algorithm, loops

It's about Rasberry PI, but in this case, it doesn't matter.
I have 9 functions like:

`for_1..9()`

These functions turn on one part of a 4-digit LED display. But I want to use a button for every number on this display, so I want to call different functions every time when I push the button. No idea how can it be.

Functions look like this:

```
def for_1():
    GPIO.output(15.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(18.HIGH)
    ....
```

Smth like this:

```
if Pin.input(number of pin):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        for_1()
        #next time in loop has to be next function
```

Comment: Whenever you think you need lots of variables named `foo_1,..., foo_1000`, there's 98% chance you actually need a `list` of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
if Pin.input(number of pin):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        globals()['for_'+str(i)]()
```

or

```
if Pin.input(number of pin):
    for i in range(0, 9):
        locals()['for_'+str(i)]()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put functions in iterables like so

```
def f():
    return 1

def g():
    return 2

for fn in [f, g]:
    print(fn())
# 1
# 2
```

Just put your required functions in a container that can be iterated over and then call them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a dynamic way to call each function for different iteration cycle.

- Define all your functions i.e. from `for_1` ... `for_9`,
- import the file which defines these functions into your main script
- Use python's `getattr` to get the function and finally invoke it.

The following code assumes that functions and iteration logic is in the same module. However you can define your functions in a separate file and import them in your iteration logic script.

```
import sys

thismodule = sys.modules[__name__] #This fetches the current module refrence

def for_1():
   return 1

for i in range(1, 10):
    func = getattr(thismodule, "for_{}".format(i))
    func() #This will invoke for_1 ... for_9
```

Comment: Thank you so much)